Build path entry is missing: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_, (Error: Unable to initialize main class: javalangNoClassDefFoundError)
So I recently copied my files from my previous hard drive onto a new hard drive i was using and I installed eciplse new version which is the JDK22 version but when I imported the files into the new IDE it's showed me (Build path entry is missing: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError).
i tried the remove and add libibarie in the "Java Build Path Section" and it worked but then the classes of all my projects began displaying "Error: Unable to initialize main class Start
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [LString;
No solutions online worked but by mistake i discovered a simple solution,
In the "Java Build Path Section" before you choose the updated "JRE System Libary" you are given the oppurtunity to choose a execution environment filled with all previous libaries, pick the most recent library close and apply, then go back and pick the current library and the problem is solved.
My files were from the JDK17 IDE and the previous was the 2021 version. Just thought i should put this out since no solution online worked for me.
